# In R, choose dataframes from menu and use bind_rows

Tags: r, rows, bind

I have a selectInput w/ 9 different reports (dataframes).  Users could choose them in any order.  I want to the user's choices to load the individual dataframes into one using bind_rows.  I have the bind_rows figured out.

In a menu dataframe I have the selectInput text and the name of the associated dataframe

```
mnuItem   df
choiceA   dfA
choiceB   dfB

dplyr::bind_rows(dfA,dfB)
```

The dataframes are already populated but the bind_rows fails w/ a message that it can not locate dfA or that it does not exist.  I an passing the string/name of the df rather than the object.  How do I get bind_rows to use the named dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `get` to return the value of the object

```
dplyr::bind_rows(get('dfA'), get('dfB'))
```

Comment: So I wonder how to get to that?  I have a selectInput with names of the dataframes.   read the input$df to get  "dfa" "dfb".  Need to convert that to what  is shown in the accepted answer.